# Closing Excel file after reading

Tags: excel-2007

Here is my code for opening the Excel file and reading the data, everything is working fine but what I would like is to close once the Excel file is read, how would i do that? I try `Dispose` the object but did not help.

```
public static DataTable ExcelWorkbook(string workbookName)
        {
            string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""", FILENAME);
            string query = String.Format("select * from [{0}$]", workbookName);

            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

            dataAdapter.Dispose();

            DataTable myTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
            if (myTable != null)
                return myTable;

            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look sth like that:

```
OleDbConnection connection;
OleDbDataAdapter clientsAdapter new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

connectionString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""",FILENAME);
connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();

clientsAdapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [{0}$]", connection);

DataTable data = new DataTable("MyTable");
clientsAdapter.Fill(data);
myDataSet.Tables.Add(data);

connection.Close();
```

After the connection is closed, the excel file will be unlocked.

Comment: after i implement your code and closing the connection, my excel file is still open.

Comment: i'm not sure how your whole program operates. 
you should use a "clean" project to evaluate the code. 
it might take a couple of seconds for the lock to be removed though.

Comment: i dont see where you have a line where it says closing the excel object? i have tried creating a fresh new project but it does not close.. after i run the code like reading the excel file i still see that my excel is open in read-only mode.

Answer (score 0):

You are disposing the data adapter that read the data, not the reference to the Excel file itself.

Somewhere in your code, you will have opened the workbook.  You need to call

```
workbook.Close();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbookclass.close(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: i am not using `workbook` i am just opening the excel file and reading and returning the `DataTable`